# Date Picker Dialog not showing in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-datepicker

Date Picker Dialog not showing in Fragment

1. I want to show date picker dialog if edittext is clicked
2. show date from date picked to edittext

```
 class VerifikasiInfoPribadiFragment : BaseFragment() {
        override fun getLayoutResId(): Int = R.layout.fragment_verifikasi_info_pribadi

        override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
            edtTanggalLahir.setOnClickListener {
                showDatePicker()
            }
        }

        private fun showDatePicker() {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

            val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
                requireActivity(),
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    edtTempatLahir.setText("" + dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year)
                },
                year,
                month,
                dayOfMonth
            )
            datePicker.show()
        }
    }
```

i've try in Activity look good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is happening because you called showDatePicker() in onActivityCreated()
     according to the life cycle, though the activity has created right now, the fragment might not be created yet so try calling the method inside onViewCreated()
or onCreateView()

Comment: Yes, you should call showDatePicker() fun from fragment onViewCreated function.

Also 
On your EditText set attributes android:focusable="false" and android:enabled="true". And set OnClickListener to that EditText. The click on that Edittext triggers the onClick() method but it can't be edited. I just tried it.

Comment: i've try onViewCreate, onCreateView, onResume. but, not work (editText)

and i've try in Button. but, not work (Button) @DashrathRathod

Comment: @AfdalDev can you share the complete code because I have tried with the codes In the Question and that worked fine for me. there was no problem in your code the only different Is I have Inflated the layout in onViewCreated() which is missing in your code

Comment: sorry, i wrong call fragment layout. its work now. thanks

Comment: @AfdalDev happy coding :)